# Normalize or denormalize for storing revision histories in a RDBMS?

Tags: sql, database-design, schema, rdbms

I have a basic CRUD web app where people can create articles/edit them. I now want to add the ability to keep revision histories of all edits. Currently, I have an Articles table that looks like this:

```
Article(id, title, content, author_id, category_id, format)
```

I have considered 2 options for changing my current schema to add support for revision history. Basic idea is every single edit for any article is stored as a record in a Revision table. So Articles and Revisions is a One-to-many relationship.

1st option (normalized):
One table for article metadata, one for revisions. No duplicate data stored.

```
Article(id, title, category_id)
Revision(id, content, author_id, format)
```

2nd option (de-normalized):
Two tables like option 1 but with some duplicate columns.

```
Article(id, title, content, author_id, category_id, format)
Revision(id, article_id, content, author_id, format)
```

I'm thinking of going with the 2nd option because it will make my coding much easier (less complex, less lines of code). I know it isn't "academic" and "pure" but my personal feeling is that having to do extra joins would hurt code maintenance. Also, performance should be better since not as many joins will have to be done.

Is this a sound way to go about this task? Possibly any unforeseen or long-term consequences I am overlooking?

Comment: JNK is right (although not SQL in se is optimized for joins - RDBMS are. Detail though). We have a similar problem for our invoicing application, but there the 'history' table is an exact copy of the invoice table, with a few additional fields (history PK, timestamp, etc). Easy to `INSERT INTO HISTORY SELECT NULL,NOW(),...,i.* from invoices i`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The performance argument is nonsense - you are doing less `JOIN`s, but RDBMS are optimized for `JOIN`s.

However you are potentially pulling a **lot** more data from the server than is necessary, which can't be optimized away.

You also potentially have a **consistency** issue.  Duplicating data for the same item in different tables leads to the ability to have inconsistencies.  What if the revision records and the article record have different values for `format` or `author`?  How do you know which is correct? What if the `content` in `Articles` doesn't match any of the revisions?

You really should normalize this.  I would add a `CurrentRevision` field to your `Articles` table to link to the current version, and you should have an `ArticleID` in the `Revisions` table to link the two together.

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on this. I realize now that code to maintain consistency may end up being more work..

Comment: Would a CurrentRevision field really be necessary? It would mean 3 calls to the DB everytime an article is created or edited: 
1. create article
2. create revision with reference to article from step (1)
3. update article.current_revision with revision from step (2)

Comment: @trinth There's no reason those all need to be separate calls, though.  You can make one call to insert the article and the reference, you just need to handle the ID values in your code correctly.

Answer (score 8):

If you care about your data, you will not end up with less code in "denormalized" case - you'll have to enforce that the latest row in  `Revision` always matches the copy in `Article`. This is actually far from trivial in the concurrent environment - you'll have to do your locking very carefully!

*(If you choose `Revision` and `Article` not to contain the same copy, then this is even worse - you won't be able to rely on DBMS for enforcing the `Revision` primary key!)*

With a DBMS powerful enough, you could have your cake and eat it too - for example, Oracle materialized views can "pre-JOIN" the data for you without any need for denormalizing the actual data model.

Even if you don't have such a  DBMS, consider denormalizing only after you have **measured** the performance on realistic amounts of data. Yes, JOINS can be expensive, but are they *too* expensive in your particular situation? Only measurements can tell.

---

BTW, consider using identifying relationship / natural key like this:

[image]

The `revision_no` grows monotonically as you add revisions under the given article.

The B-Tree structure underneath the `Revision` PK makes it very efficient to find the latest (or any!) revision of the given article. Unless you have alternate keys not shown in your question, you could also [cluster](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) the `Revision` and (under Oracle) even compress the leading edge of the clustering index, so space overhead from repeating `article_id` is annulled.

Comment: I learned a lot from your comment and I'll be going with the normalized option. I am selecting the other answer as the "solution" though because his suggestion is what I ended up using.

Comment: @trinth Be careful about `Article.CurrentRevision`. Presumably, the `Revision` is already ordered on some field, and the last revision can be naturally inferred from that order. So, `CurrentRevision` doesn't introduce any new information to the system, it just duplicates the existing one - it is **redundant** and redundancies lead to modification anomalies. You are not even getting any performance advantage from its existence (in a B-tree, searching for MAX is as fast as searching for concrete value). Its existence is justified only if "last" and "current" revision mean different things.